# Gomoku game with socket client(multithread) and server

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

I've write a gomoku terminal game with socket client and server.

The main suggestions I am looking for:

- Am I using the multithread in right way? As when I tried to migrate the terminal game to GUI(pygame), the main thread is blocking, pygame can't render.
- I am new in socket in python, so any suggestions about socket all appreciate.
- Also not sure for my `singleton`, I have checked the `id`, they keep the same, but I am just new in singleton in python, is it pythonic?
- My server just accept two connection, so I tried to close the server while client close the connection, I doubt my implement

  ```
  if connection_0_data == b'':
      print("connection 0 is GONE")
      return None, None

  connection_1_data = connection[1].recv(1024)
  if connection_1_data == b'':
      print("connection 1 is GONE")
      return None, None
  ```

Any other suggestions all welcome.

(The code is bit long)

---

### Client part

```
import socket
import json
import sys
import argparse
import re
import threading
import queue
```

#### socket part, using singleton

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}
    def _singleton(*args, **kwags):
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls(*args, **kwags)
        return instances[cls]
    return _singleton

@singleton
class GomokuClient():
    def __init__(self):
        self._client = None

    @property
    def client(self):
        return self._client

    def connect(self, host, port):
        self._client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._client.connect((host, port))

    def send(self, data):
        self._client.send(json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8"))

    def receive(self):
        response = self._client.recv(4096)
        return json.loads(response.decode("utf-8"))

    def close(self):
        self._client.close()
        self._client = None
```

#### Client multithread part

this part I get from [here](https://github.com/eliben/code-for-blog/blob/master/2011/socket_client_thread_sample/socketclientthread.py)

```
class ClientCommand():
    CONNECT, SEND, RECEIVE, CLOSE = range(4)
    def __init__(self, type_, data=None):
        self.type_ = type_
        self.data = data


class GomokuClientThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, send_q=queue.Queue(), reply_q=queue.Queue()):
        super(GomokuClientThread, self).__init__()
        self.cmd_q = send_q
        self.reply_q = reply_q
        self.clientsocket = GomokuClient()
        self.handlers = {
            ClientCommand.CONNECT: self.connect,
            ClientCommand.CLOSE: self.close,
            ClientCommand.SEND: self.send,
            ClientCommand.RECEIVE: self.recieve,
        }

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                cmd = self.cmd_q.get(True, 0.1)
                self.handlers[cmd.type_](cmd.data)
            except queue.Empty as e:
                continue

    def connect(self, data):
        host, port = data
        self.clientsocket.connect(host, port)
        self.cmd_q.put(ClientCommand(ClientCommand.RECEIVE))

    def send(self, data):
        if data.get("grid"):
            data["grid"] = self.grid_matrix_2_str(data["grid"])
        self.clientsocket.send(data)
        self.cmd_q.put(ClientCommand(ClientCommand.RECEIVE))

    def recieve(self, data=None):
        data = self.clientsocket.receive()
        if data:
            self.reply_q.put(data)

    def close(self, data=None):
        self.clientsocket.close()

    def grid_matrix_2_str(self, grid):
        n = len(grid)
        m = len(grid[0])
        return "".join("".join(str(grid[i][j]) for j in range(m)) for i in range(n))
```

#### Game part

```
class GomokuGame():
    def __init__(self, player, board_row=5, board_column=5, host="localhost", port=50003):
        self.board_row = board_row
        self.board_column = board_column
        self.player = player
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def display(self):
        client_thread = GomokuClientThread()
        client_thread.start()
        client_thread.cmd_q.put(ClientCommand(ClientCommand.CONNECT, (self.host, self.port)))
        while True:
            data = client_thread.reply_q.get(True)
            grid = self.grid_str_2_matrix(data["grid"])
            if data["gameover"] == -1:
                if data["next_player"] != self.player:
                    client_thread.cmd_q.put(ClientCommand(ClientCommand.SEND, {"wait": True}))
                else:
                    self.print_grid(grid)
                    grid, x, y = self.next_move(grid)
                    self.print_grid(grid)
                    print("Waiting...")
                    data = {"grid":grid, "x":x, "y":y, "player":self.player}
                    client_thread.cmd_q.put(ClientCommand(ClientCommand.SEND, data))
            else:
                if data["gameover"] == 0:
                    print("Draw")
                else:
                    if data["player"] == self.player:
                        print("You Win")
                    else:
                        print("You Lost")
                client_thread.cmd_q.put(ClientCommand(ClientCommand.CLOSE))
                break

    def grid_str_2_matrix(self, grid):
        return [list(map(int, grid[i:i+self.board_column])) for i in range(0, len(grid), self.board_column)]

    def print_grid(self, grid):
        print("\n".join([" | ".join(list(map(str, grid[i]))) for i in range(self.board_row)]))

    def next_move(self, grid):
        while True:
            position = input(f"What's your next move, separate by ',', only integer between 0-{self.board_row} allowed:")
            x, y = position.split(",")
            try:
                x = int(x)
                y = int(y)
                if grid[x][y] == 0:
                    grid[x][y] = self.player
                    break
                print(f"Already has piece on {x}/{y}")
            except:
                pass
        return grid, x, y

    def __call__(self):
        return self.display()
```

#### Run the game

```
def parse_options():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='%(prog)s [options]',
                                     description='Gomoku socket client @Qin',
                                     formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                                     epilog=
'''
Examples:
python server.py -i '0.0.0.0' -p 9999
'''
                                        )
    parser.add_argument('-i','--ip', type=str, default="localhost", help='server host')
    parser.add_argument('-p','--port', type=int, default=9999, help='server port')
    parser.add_argument('-e','--player', type=int, default=1, help='player')
    args = parser.parse_args()


    ip_pattern = "((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:(?<!\.)|\.)){4}"
    ip = re.match(ip_pattern, args.ip)
    valid_ip = (ip and ip.group(0) == args.ip)

    if not (args.ip == "localhost" or valid_ip):
        print("[-] IPV4 host is not valid")
        sys.exit(1)
    return args

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_options()
    game = GomokuGame(args.player, host=args.ip, port=args.port)
    game()
```

---

### Server Part

```
import socket
import json
import random
import threading
import argparse
import re

class GomokuServer():
    '''
    Package:
        Server -> Client: 
                          grid => grid(str, with 0 1 and 2)
                          x => last move x position(int)
                          y => last move y position(int) 
                          player => Last Player(int)
                          next_player => who's next player(int)
                          gameover => is gameover(int), -1=No, 0=Draw, 1=Player Win

        Client -> Server: (case 1: with move)
                          grid => grid(str, with 0 1 and 2)
                          x => last move x position(int)
                          y => last move y position(int) 
                          player => Last Player(int)

                          (case 2: without move)
                          wait => (always be True)

    '''

    def __init__(self, host, port, board_row, board_column):
        self.board_row = board_row
        self.board_column = board_column
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

    def listen(self):
        self.sock.listen(2)
        print(f"Listing {self.host}:{self.port}")
        connection = []

        while True:
            self.waiting_for_connections(connection)
            self.listen_2_clients(connection)

    def close(self):
        self.sock.close()

    def listen_2_clients(self, connection):
        self.response = {"grid":"0"*(self.board_row*self.board_column), 
                         "x": -1,
                         "y": -1,
                         "player": -1,
                         "next_player": 1,
                         "gameover": -1}
        while True:
            data_arr = json.dumps(self.response).encode("utf-8")
            connection[0].send(data_arr)
            connection[1].send(data_arr)

            player1, player2 = self.recieve_information(connection)

            if player1 is None:
                self.sock.close()
                break

            self.response = self.process_positions(player1, player2)


    def waiting_for_connections(self, connection):
        while len(connection)<2:
            conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
            conn.settimeout(60)
            connection.append(conn)
            print(conn)
            print(connection)

    def recieve_information(self, connection):
        connection_0_data = connection[0].recv(1024)
        if connection_0_data == b'':
            print("connection 0 is GONE")
            return None, None

        connection_1_data = connection[1].recv(1024)
        if connection_1_data == b'':
            print("connection 1 is GONE")
            return None, None
        player_1_info = json.loads(connection_0_data.decode("utf-8"))
        player_2_info = json.loads(connection_1_data.decode("utf-8"))

        return player_1_info, player_2_info

    def process_positions(self, player1, player2):
        if not player1.get("wait"):
            grid = player1["grid"]
            player = player1["player"]
            x = player1["x"]
            y = player1["y"]
        else:
            grid = player2["grid"]
            player = player2["player"]
            x = player2["x"]
            y = player2["y"]
        grid = self.grid_str_2_matrix(grid)
        if self._check_win(grid, [x, y], player):
            gameover = 1
        elif self._check_draw(grid):
            gameover = 0
        else:
            gameover = -1
        grid = self.grid_matrix_2_str(grid)
        return {"grid":grid, "x":x, "y":y, "player":player, "next_player":3-player, "gameover":gameover}

    def grid_str_2_matrix(self, grid):

        return [list(map(int, grid[i:i+self.board_column])) for i in range(0, len(grid), self.board_column)]

    def grid_matrix_2_str(self, grid):
        return "".join("".join(str(grid[i][j]) for j in range(self.board_column)) for i in range(self.board_row))

    def _check_draw(self, grid):
        return all([grid[i][j] != 0 for i in range(self.board_row) for j in range(self.board_column)])

    def _check_win(self, grid, position, player):
        target = player
        if grid[position[0]][position[1]] != target:
            return False
        directions = [([0, 1], [0, -1]), ([1, 0], [-1, 0]), ([-1, 1], [1, -1]), ([1, 1], [-1, -1])]
        for direction in directions:
            continue_chess = 0
            for i in range(2):
                p = position[:]
                while 0 <= p[0] < self.board_row and 0 <= p[1] < self.board_column:
                    if grid[p[0]][p[1]] == target:
                        continue_chess += 1
                    else:
                        break
                    p[0] += direction[i][0]
                    p[1] += direction[i][1]

            if continue_chess >= 6:
                return True
        return False

    def __call__(self):
        return self.listen()

def parse_options():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='%(prog)s [options]',
                                     description='Gomoku socket server @Qin',
                                     formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                                     epilog=
'''
Examples:
python server.py -i '0.0.0.0' -p 9999
'''
                                        )
    parser.add_argument('-i','--ip', type=str, default="localhost", help='server host')
    parser.add_argument('-p','--port', type=int, default=9999, help='server port')
    parser.add_argument('-r','--row', type=int, default=15, help='board row length')
    parser.add_argument('-c','--column', type=int, default=15, help='board column length')

    args = parser.parse_args()


    ip_pattern = "((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:(?<!\.)|\.)){4}"
    ip = re.match(ip_pattern, args.ip)
    valid_ip = (ip and ip.group(0) == args.ip)

    if not (args.ip == "localhost" or valid_ip):
        print("[-] IPV4 host is not valid")
        sys.exit(1)
    return args

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_options()
    server = GomokuServer(args.ip, args.port, args.row, args.column)
    try:
        server()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.close()
```